# Verify DNS in Microsoft via Powershell or AzureCLI

Tags: powershell, microsoft

I have a question regarding admin.microsoft.com.
Is it possible to verify DNS via PowerShell or Azure CLI or do something similar to what this page is doing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want to verify a DNS domain that you've [Added to O365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-domain). For that, you can use [**Confirm-MsolDomain**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/confirm-msoldomain?view=azureadps-1.0) and the associated cmdlets. For example:

```
# Authenticate to MS Online
Connect-MsolService

# list current domain(s) and their status
Get-MsolDomain

# Add a new domain
New-MsolDomain -Name 'contoso.com'

# Get the DNS TXT record verification details
Get-MsolDomainVerificationDns -DomainName 'contoso.com' -Mode DnsTxtRecord

### Create your TXT record before continuing ###

# Verify your domain
Confirm-MsolDomain -DomainName 'contoso.com'
```